# i want to set a searchview over an imageview in a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to set search view over the imageview in the linear layout. 
It's easy when we are using the Constraint Layout by dragging over it but I want to do this in LinearLayout

Please Help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `FrameLayout`(or `RelativeLayout`) within your `LinearLayout` and have search view and `ImageView` inside the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: The LinearLayout then becomes **useless**. And bad for performances (as always, with nested layout designs)

Comment: @Fantômas I am assuming the author has other items in his LinearLayout, which he did not care to mention.

Comment: Well, but... then a different container would be probably more adequate.